# Why does this loop stop at 99999

Tags: javascript

I run this code in the editor

```
let flag = true;
let counter = 0;
while(flag === true){
    console.log(counter);
    counter+=1;
    if (counter === 100000){
        break;
    }
}
```

And I want to ask why this code stops at 99999. In the if block, it says that if `counter` is equal to 100000 the loop will stop. Why does it stop at 99999?

Comment: `while(flag === true)` : in your code you are showing, `flag` is always `true`. Why is this condition here ?

Comment: Because you break before you log the final value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let flag = true;
let counter = 0;
while(flag === true){
   counter+=1; // from 99999 to 100000
   console.log(counter); // counter is 100000

   if (counter === 10){
     break;
   }
}
```

Just replace the rows of console log and the increment row with each other.

As you printed the counter and only after incremented the counter you get the value of the last iteration, if you change the rows as I suggested the counter you print is the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the increment after the check.

Then you get `100000` as well, because the output is earlier and the condition checks the incremented value.

```js
let flag = true;
let counter = 0;

while (flag) {
    console.log(counter);     // <--\ allow an output
    if (counter === 100000) { // ---/ of the last value
        break;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop *does* stop when `counter` is equal to 100000. However, the last number you will see printed out is 99999. This is why:

```
let flag = true;
let counter = 0;
while(flag === true){
    // suppose this is the last iteration
    console.log(counter); // 99999 is printed here
    counter+=1; // now counter is 100000
    if (counter === 100000){ // this becomes true
        break; // the loop stops!
    }
}
```

One way to make it print 100000 is to add another `console.log` before `break`.